# Unity gameObject without a script is reaching a collision method

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I am taking a class in basic game development and am currently working on a game with Unity. My game worked perfectly up until now when I updated my unity version. In order for the player to actually take damage I have a method that can only be reached if explicitly called by a script. Somehow the ground, that has no script attached, damages my player.

I have posted the code below.

This one is part of the player script

```
3 references
public void Hurt(int dmg, string yep)
    {
        HP -= dmg;
        Debug.Log($"took {dmg} damage from{yep}. You now have {HP} HP left");
        if (HP <= 0)
        {
            SceneManagement.Death();
        }
    }
```

This one is part of the script attatched to my flame object

```
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag != "FlameTurret" && collision.gameObject.tag != "flame")
        {
            player.GetComponent<PlayerController>().Hurt(damage, collision.gameObject.tag);
             Destroy(this.gameObject);
        } 
    }
```

This one is attatched to a projectile fired by the enemy

```
if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            if (!called)
            {
                collision.gameObject.GetComponent<PlayerController>().Hurt(damage, collision.gameObject.tag);
                called = true;
            }
        }
```

This one is attatched to an enemy

```
if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            if (!called)
            {
                collision.gameObject.GetComponent<PlayerController>().Hurt(damage, collision.gameObject.tag);    
                called = true;
            }
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
        }
```

[Console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lpdR.png)

Nothing with the tag "Ground" has a script and nothing else than the methods i've posted are supposed to reference my Hurt() method but the ground still damages my player. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be that this function here

```
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
```

Will be run whenever *any* collider (game object with a collider component attached - the game object does not need to have any scripts attached to it) intersects with your player

This code here

```
 if (collision.gameObject.tag != "FlameTurret" && collision.gameObject.tag != "flame")
```

Will pass so long as the object that collides does *not* have the tag of `"FlameTurret"` or `"flame"`, which I assume your ground does not.
It seems to me a little odd that everything in your game will damage your player *except* for flames... is this an error?
Either way a simple fix would be to tag your ground with something like `environment` and then add under your `OnCollisionEnter2D()` have a check along the lines of

```
 if (collision.gameObject.tag == "environment"){
    return; // do nothing
}
```

Comment: Sorry it appears I was being unclear, these collisions are under different objects. I'll edit my post to try and make it a bit clearer

Comment: @Handensaken ahh i see, If you comment out each of the places where `Hurt()` is called (or perhaps better use a breakpoint and stack trace) can you work out which of your three calls is happening when the ground is damaging the player?